# String file don't open as ASCII Property List in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, zendesk, localizable.strings

I am trying to do this:
https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001075348-Hide-the-Leave-a-message-button-in-the-Chat-SDK

And want to update the string ios.ZDCChat.noAgentsMessage in my ZDCChatStrings.bundle.
IF I right-click the strings file in the bundle and select Open As > ASCII Property List, it gives an error and doesn't open.

Error says:

> Tried to create a document (class: IDEPlistDocument) and got a
> document with a different, non-conforming fileType back instead.

Here's a screenshot of how the Localizable.strings file opens on my end, if I change anything in this as it is, it stops working too. [image]

Here's the string file which don't opens correctly in Xcode - and I am unable to change string in it due to that:
https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_sdk_chat_ios/blob/master/ZDCChatStrings.bundle/en.lproj/Localizable.strings

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks as if you are trying to open a directory?

Comment: no @skaak it's Localizable.strings file- I shared a screenshot of how it shows in my question, Thank you.

Comment: Change the extension to ```.plist``` and try again.

Comment: Hey @skaak that works too. Though I was able to do my text update using /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy! Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. The solution suggested by *skaak* in comment above works too, i.e.
   Change the extension to .plist and it makes the file readable which can be updated.
2. But if you don't want to change the extension, and want to replace the string within the strings file, then this can be used: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c